# Why Python giving me UnboundLocalError?

Tags: python

My Python program giving me a unbound error but i cant get it why

(Error occurs at connectionstat function)

Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import requests
g = "noinput"
passhash = open("atlaspass.txt", "r")
systracer = "noinput"
var_tarih = date.today()
var_zaman = datetime.now()
#def fallbackid():
   # print("Atlas yanìt vermiyor")
def about():
           settings_about_version = open('atlasver.txt', 'r')
           settings_about_version.seek(0)     #Dosyayı baştan okur
           print("Atlas Versiyonu: " ,settings_about_version.readline())
           settings_about_codename = open('atlascodename.txt', "r")
           settings_about_codename.seek(0)
           print("Atlas ", settings_about_codename.readline())
           print()
def connectionstat():
    url = "http://google.com"
    timeout = 5
    try:
        request = request.get(url, timeout = timeout)
        print('İnternete Bağlı')
    except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as exception:
        print("İnternet Bağlantısı Yok")
def logon():
    tokenhash = passhash.readline()
    while True:
        atlaslogon = input("Lütfen Şifrenizi Giriniz: ")
        if atlaslogon != tokenhash:
            print('Şifre Yanlış')
        if atlaslogon == tokenhash:
            print("Şifre Doğru")
            break          
def desktop_apps():
    print("[1] - Ayarlar")
def desktop():
    print()
    print()
    print()
    print('Hoşgeldiniz')
    print()
    print()
    zaman = var_zaman.strftime("%H:%M")
    print(zaman ,  var_tarih)
    print()
    desktop_apps()
logon()
desktop()
connectionstat()
```

I runned the program from Pydroid (I am using Android because i dont have a Personal Computer)

The result is

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment

Full Output is

```
Lütfen Şifrenizi Giriniz: j4debug
Şifre Doğru



Hoşgeldiniz


14:34 2022-11-15

[1] - Ayarlar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 51, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 23, in connectionstat
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment
[Program finished]
```

Please explain why Python giving me a unbound error

I am a newbie sorry if i made mistakes

Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: The library name is `requests` so use `requests.get(...)` not `request.get(...)`.

Comment: Please edit your question with the required information. Check on [How to ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In regard to your query, the variable `request` is called without reference. Either pass it as an import from the requests module or declare the variable even before the call if the importing from requests is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line from `request = request.get(url, timeout = timeout)` to
`request = requests.get(url, timeout = timeout)`.

Note that the library is called `requests` and not `request`.

Comment: This the right solution thanks but i cant accept that as answer because website saying you need to wait 10 minutes to accept an answer